# Array as function parameter error finding the length of the array

Tags: c++, c

```
1.  int minimum(int arr[]){
2.
3.     int min,pos = 0;
4.     min =  arr[0];
5.     int i;
6.     for(i = 0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));i++){
7.         if(arr[i]<min){
8.             min = arr[i];
9.             pos = i;
10.        }
11.     }
12.     return arr[pos];
13.  }
```

in the 6th line it the satement in the for loop condition cant count the size of the array .......

Comment: Short answer: You cannot.

Comment: Are you using `C` or `C++`?  If it's `C++`, then `std::array<>` is what you're looking for.  Regular arrays are dumb as they do not know they're size (easily).

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) some indormation how you can format your code properly when posting at this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int minimum(int arr[])
```

the number of elements is unknown at compile time, `sizeof(arr)` cannot values the right value, it will values `sizeof(int *)` because this is the type of *arr*

But in

```
void f()
{
   int arr[3];

   printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
}
```

the sizeof of *arr* is known at compile time

Comment: In `int minimum(int arr[42])` the number of elements is *still* unknown by the compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I wasn't enough clear, I edit, thank you for the advice